# Error compiling Delphi Application to Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, delphi, compiler-errors

When I try to compile to a Ubuntu Linux 20.04, I'm receiving this message below:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lGL
```

I have installed the dependencies according Embarcadero Help.

How do I proceed?

Delphi Rio 10.3.3

Comment: What type of application? Which help topic? Guessing since it looks like missing OpenGL support you didn't install the requirements in the FireMonkey for Linux help topic.

Comment: It's a console application and I followed this embarcadero's help.http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Linux_Application_Development

Could be some project unit incompatible?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was the Firedac.VCLUI.Wait unit, the provider property was wrong, must be Console.

Answer (score 0):

Better explaining, I had to include the TFDGUIxWaitCursor component and change the property to "console"